# Error trying to install Visual Studio Community 2019 Extensions

Tags: visual-studio

I just go into Extensions>Manage Extensions>Update, click "Update All" and then close Visual Studio.
The installation just give me a error, i searched online but no clue what's wrong.

Already repaired and reinstalled completely visual studio

Any help? This is the error log.

```
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - -------------------------------------------
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - 16.9.2017
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - -------------------------------------------
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - Command line parameters:
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - A:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:A:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Community,/skuVersion:16.9.31313.79,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019,/culture:en-US,/noep,C:\Users\erikm\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXdc234dfy.vsix,C:\Users\erikm\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXygjj5kfo.vsix,C:\Users\erikm\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXityxfypz.vsix
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - -------------------------------------------
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - -------------------------------------------
22/05/2021 22:41:45 - System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation, Version=15.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation, Version=15.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.AddInstalledIsolatedShells(Version vsVersion, IntPtr userToken)
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.InitializeSupportedSKUs(IntPtr userToken)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.InitializeSupportedSKUs(ICommandLineData cmdLineData, IntPtr duplicatedUserToken)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62735293/466577

Comment: i tried and i get the same error

Comment: Please check this one too. Maybe you will find something useful there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting all "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation.dll" found by a file explorer search and reinstalling visual studio, it worked!